# Boot Error when booting from USB flash drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive

My HDD crashed (probably due to a high re-allocated sector count), so I made a bootable USB flash drive with Ubuntu 10.04 live on it. But I get the error:

```
BOOT ERROR
```

I disconnected my HDD and tried again, but it's still the same.

So, is there something I may be doing wrong? Or is a HDD required to boot into a live USB?

**EDIT:**
I have the boot order as USB drive first.
I also selected the USB drive during the boot process.
The USB drive is good and boots well on other systems.